# F# write a string of text letter by letter without using loops

Tags: f#

I'm doing functional programming with F# at the moment and I'm quite stuck on this. I want to print out a string of text letter by letter without using a loop as that isn't considered functional. I have a very primitive way here:

```
printf "W"
Thread.Sleep(200)
printf "e"
Thread.Sleep(200)
printf "l"
Thread.Sleep(200)
printf "c"
Thread.Sleep(200)
printf "o"
Thread.Sleep(200)
printf "m"
Thread.Sleep(200)
printf "e "
```

but obviously, I cannot do that for a 150 character string. If anyone can provide some help or point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciative. Thanks

Comment: well, you can use `Seq.iter`

Comment: As long as you care about what is "considered functional", you should know that producing side effects (such as printing or waiting) isn't so considered. But if you just want your program to run correctly, loops are fine.

Comment: btw, just curious why do you think that using loops it bad practice?

Comment: Just what we've been going through in class. Having something functional mainly uses recursion/pipelining rather than loops.

Comment: Well, but you have to think _why_ loops are "bad" specifically. If you just repeat the mantra parrot-fashion, that doesn't help you to build better software. That's what is usually called a "cult". One of the reasons loops are frowned upon is that they are usually used to produce side effects. From this, it's easy to see that if you're producing side effects anyway, doing it without loops is no better.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that explanation, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, blocking a thread and printing are side-effects and so they are not really functional on their own. The nice thing about F# is that you can do side-effects easily if you need to. Typically, you will have some core functional logic, called from a bit of code that does the interaction with user using side-effects.

As you really just need to iterate over a word, `for` loop does this perfectly:

```
let msg = "Welcome"
for c in msg do 
  printf "%c" c
  Thread.Sleep(200)
```

But since you asked about more functional ways, one thing you could learn using this example is recursion (which is quite important in functional programming in general). You can transform `for` loop into a recursive function like this:

```
let rec printChars chars = 
  match chars with
  | [] -> ()
  | c::rest ->
      printfn "%c" c
      Thread.Sleep(200)
      printChars rest

let msg = "Welcome"
printChars (List.ofSeq msg)
```

This is not what I'd normally write - because there is no point making code more complicated - but it is useful learning exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanations. Two things though, what does [] -> () mean and the second one is brilliant for me as I'm still learning, but it prints the letters vertically not horizontally in a line when I implement it into my own code.

Comment: `[] -> ()` means "when the input is empty list, do nothing, i.e. return the unit value `()`; the vertical vs. horizontal thing is because I used `printfn` which inserts new line

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks again, your explanations really helped.